# What is a non-trivial example of an unbounded subdifferential?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, examples, convex-analysis

Let $f: X \to [ -\infty, \infty]$ be some function,

Can someone provide a non-trivial example where the subdifferential evaluated at a point $x$,
$$\partial f(x)$$ is "unbounded"? (trivial examples included the improper functions)

A rough definition of an unbounded subgradient is that there exists some sequence $v_n \in \partial f(x)$ such that $\|v_n\| \to \infty$.

Comment: Observation: If a function has unbounded subdifferential, suppose without loss it occurs at $0$ and $f(0) = 0$ (you can always translate so that this is the case); then $f(v_n) \geq \|v_n\|_2^2$, for all $n$. Hence $\liminf f(v_n) \geq +\infty$.

Comment: This should happen at zero for $\sqrt{|x|}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example is the convex function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \infty, & \text{if}\ x<0\\
x & \text{if}\ x\geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
It holds that $\partial f(0) = ]-\infty,1]$.

There are no examples without the value $\infty$: If $f$ is convex and bounded in a neighborhood at some point, then $f$ is locally Lipschitz at that point and hence, the subgradient at that point is bounded.

If you do not assume convexity, you can get unbounded subgradients even for bounded functions as a comment to the question shows.

Comment: Thank you. If I visualize the graph it really makes a lot of sense.